# How to change an Icon when a div open/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');
        var $icon = $(this).next('.icons');

        $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
        if ($div.is(":visible")) {
            $.hide();
        }  else {
            $div.show();
        }

        $("span.icons").not($icon).show();
        if ($icon.is(":visible")) {
            $.hide();
        }  else {
            $(".icons").text('-');

        }
    });

    $(document).click(function(e){
        var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown__dlk').length
        if (!p) {
            $(".dropdown-container").hide();
            $(".icons").text('+');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box__dlk--dropdown">
<div id="dropdown__dlk-1" class="dropdown__dlk dropdown-processed">
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">GRUPO DE INFORMAÇÂO <span class="icons">+</span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
        chamada 01
    </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown__dlk-2" class="dropdown__dlk dropdown-processed">
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">AVALIAÇÃO <span class="icons">+</span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
        chamada 02
    </div>
</div>

<div id="dropdown__dlk-3" class="dropdown__dlk dropdown-processed">
    <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">TABELA DE MEDIDAS <span class="icons">+</span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
        chama 03
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I click to open another div, the icon - doesn't  back for  , only when i click outside. I don't understand much of JS and Jquery, and if  possible, chan explain me what it's wrong ?
This is an update for my last question

Comment: The way you are making the `div` hide or show, in the same way, have two icons and show/hide the icons.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: please see the answer. Run the snippet and check.

Comment: I highly recommend you **don't** use `.next()` or any other document pathing method.  By doing this, you create fragile code that by definition is coupled to your html markup structure.  Instead, decorate your elements withs classes, and use classes to navigate your elements.  [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cleaned up your code a bit.

- Since `span` having class `icons` is not a sibling of the link, `next()` won't work. Used `children()` and took the first one.
- In the save show/hide logic included the icon text change as well.
- Removed the unnecessary even handler block at the end

Here is the running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Click Events</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="box__dlk--dropdown">
        <div id="dropdown__dlk-1" class="dropdown__dlk dropdown-processed">
            <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">GRUPO DE INFORMAÇÂO <span class="icons">+</span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
                chamada 01
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="dropdown__dlk-2" class="dropdown__dlk dropdown-processed">
            <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">AVALIAÇÃO <span class="icons">+</span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
                chamada 02
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="dropdown__dlk-3" class="dropdown__dlk dropdown-processed">
            <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">TABELA DE MEDIDAS <span class="icons">+</span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
                chama 03
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("a.dropdown-link").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');
                var $icon = $(this).children('.icons').first();

                $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
                $(".icons").not($icon).text('+');
                if ($div.is(":visible")) {
                    $div.hide();
                    $icon.text('+');
                } else {
                    $div.show();
                    $icon.text('-');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** Depending on how you display (span, image, CSS, etc.) and where you place (sibling, child, etc.) the icon related stuff, change the above code a little bit to make it work.

Comment: YAS! Thank u, exactly what I wanted

Comment: Ok, just one more question if you dont mind. To use a CSS I just would have to change .text for .toggleClass ? I'm trying but when I open other div, the .toggleClass stay there.
`
               if ($div.is(":visible")) {
                    $div.hide();
                    $icon.className.remove('open');
                } else {
                    $div.show();
                    $icon.toggleClass('open');
                }
`

Comment: On which element you have applied the CSS class to show icon? Depending on that do: `$(element).toggleClass('plusicon', 'minusicon')`. This will make the switch between `plusicon` and `minusicon` classes. If you share your code through a fiddle or here I can take a look and help.

Comment: Yeah, sure, can it be on CodePen?
https://codepen.io/KaioRocha/pen/NWKNexQ

Comment: Check it out at the shared link: https://codepen.io/KaioRocha/pen/NWKNexQ. You can even control the `+` and `-` from css class using css property `content`.

Comment: Did you make any changes to the code? CodePen does not save like this :s. But the thing is, the "abrir" class doesn't go away when you click on another div

Comment: I have changed your code. Here is the saved one: https://codepen.io/fiveelements/pen/aboNPEE

Comment: maybe I have expressed myself badly, what I need to keep is the effect of the keyframe. That way there is no trigger for the keyframe, right? Oh, and don't get me wrong, I just really want to understand better how these things work and their limitations.

Comment: I did it! Got it! haha Thank you so much for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

You could include a div in your dropdown-link that uses `background-image: url(icon.png)` and fixed width and height values to show an image and then have css apply `transform: rotate(180deg);` or replace the image whenever the parent has the `DropDownStyle` class.

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="dropdown__dlk-1" class="dropdown__dlk dropdown-processed">
   <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">GRUPO DE INFORMAÇÂO <div class="icon"></div></a>
   <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
      chamada 01
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.dropdown__dlk div.icon {
  background-image: url(icon.png);
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
div.dropdown__dlk.DropDownStyle div.icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* alternatively replace image */
  background-image: url(icon2.png);
}
```

JS
apply DropDownStyle to whole `.dropdown-dlk`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("a.dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');

            $(".dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
            if ($div.is(":visible")) {
                $div.hide();
                $(this).addClass('DropDownStyle');

            }  else {
                $div.show();
                $(this).addClass('DropDownStyle');

            }
        });

        $(document).click(function(e){
            var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown__dlk').length
            if (!p) {
                $(".dropdown-container").hide();
            }
        });

    });
```

Note: That's how I would do it, but it's probably not the best solution. Also I didn't check my code so it might not work